# Why can't I save Chunks that contain links to CDNs?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-chunks

I have a Chunk for my header. In it I have several links to CDNs like Bootstrap, eg:

All of a sudden I can no longer save updates to this Chunk.

Same issue with copying the contents to a new Chunk.

Would anyone know what I could do?

Comment: What MODX version do you use? Did you notice any errors in web developer browser console after "save" button click? Also do you have any errors in MODX error log? What do MODX say when you press "Save" for chunk?

Comment: Version 2.5.7. No errors in console. MODX doesn't say anything when I hit the save button - the Saving... modal appears for a fraction of a second and disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue is reported here on the MODX forum:
https://community.modx.com/t/cannot-save-chunks-with-script-tags-even-after-turning-off-mod-security/

Maybe that will shed some light. Seems to be a modsecurity or firewall issue.

Edit: to say, Oh I see that *is your* post on MODX forum. Did you try their suggestions?

Comment: Haven't tried them yet. I'm going to get in touch with the server provider and see if they can do anything.